# Add "\x" to existing byte variable

Tags: python

I have the following bytestring: `y = b'36'`

If I do `print(int.from_bytes(y, "little"))`, it returns `13875`.

I want to add a `\x` to the value so the same print returns `54` which is 0x36 in decimal.

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x` is not part of the value of `b'\x36'`; it's just part of the *literal string representation* that tells the Python interpreter how to parse the value.  As such, it doesn't make sense to talking about adding it later; once parsing is complete, the `\x` doesn't exist anymore, and your value is completely indistinguishable from `b'6'`.

What you *can* do is use the [`binascii` standard-library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) to convert your value into its desired form:

```
import binascii

y = b'36'
print(int.from_bytes(binascii.a2b_hex(y), 'little'))
```

...correctly emits `54`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Renato, glad this was useful! If you don't need any further assistance, consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer, which will (in accepting an answer) mark the question as solved.